# Access 2013 Conditional Formatting Many Fields with Same Rules

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, formatting, ms-access-2013

I'm working with Access to manage weekly time sheets for ~70 employees.  Unfortunately I have to enter everything manually into Access thanks to an ancient time keeping system.

I have a table with LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, and then about 90 hour fields for each month.  The table also has to be zero'ed out (to both avoid the NULL values issue and because they require everything to be zero'ed....)  In order to make life easier for my eyes, I want to conditionally format everything that has a zero with a black background.

What's the easiest way to go about this since Access doesn't allow you to format multiple fields at the same time.  I'm using a Datasheet Form on a desktop DB.

I've been reading a bunch of things, but most seem to talk about formatting many rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done if you can create a report from your data. If you create a report from the data, switch to layout view and go to the format tab. Highlight all the fields you want to format for, and then go to conditional formatting. It should say "Show formatting rules for Multiple" at the top, and then you can create a new rule. Then just create the rule you want, which I assume would be field value is equal to 0, and then make sure it's formatted with a black background and apply!

Comment: That would work if I was done editing the data.  I still need to edit records, which is why I'd like to use the DATASHEET Form.

Comment: If you want to stick with a form, then you will have to condtionally format each field separately, or do after update commands for each control. If you want to see it while you upload then that's all you can do, however you can go ahead and create the report and then just look at it whenever you want to see the data formatted with only a little interruption in your inputting. The report will automatically update with your new data whenever you open it